# flutter make widget collapse when scroll

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a container collapse (disappear) when scroll down, and expand (appear again) when scroll up. Just like the search bar in microsoft teams mobile.

I tried to do it using SliverAppBar and it worked but the ListView became lagging and had problems. Is there any way to do it without SliverAppBar?

[image]

Comment: I think sliver will provide the best performance ., Can you include sample snippet that will be laggy

Answer (score 1):

You may check this library [hidable](https://pub.dev/packages/hidable)

Comment: I didn't like it because the animation when the widget is hide is fade and you can't change it.

Comment: Hi @Ali, I'm author of hidable package, can you please provide(in GitHub issues) what kind of customisation you might like? This would be very helpful for us to make it more usable for you guys. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should only replace `AppBar` Widget with `SliverAppBar`

hope I could help.

Comment: Hi, like i said in the question, i tried to do it using SliverAppBar and it worked but the ListView became lagging and had problems.

Comment: I meant to set SliverAppBar as a default, your provided gif shows that you are using 2 AppBars, default AppBar and the other is the SliverAppBar

Comment: The gif is not my app, its from teams mobile app.